# how json data convert to python

Tags: python, json

```
{
    serverSeconds : 1425865582,
    last_time : 1425865106,
    path : [{title : "美股", id : "49", cType : "col"}],
    count : 1332,
    offset_page : 0,
    offset_num : 0,"}
```

how make this json data convert to python data?

Comment: thank your answer,but note: eg: the key is serverSeconds that haven't quotes both sides.thisis JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes, but how to solve

Comment: That data is **not** JSON.  Preferably make the server produce proper JSON or try parsing it with a [YAML parser](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML)

Comment: url is http://roll.news.sina.com.cn/interface/rollnews_ch_out_interface.php?col=49&spec=&type=&ch=03&k=&offset_page=0&offset_num=0&num=60&asc=&page=1, getingt it html source is json data.

Comment: it is not [JSON](http://json.org/), it is JavaScript.